# How to extract Lua script to use alone from VLC?

Tags: lua, vlc

VLC uses a Lua script to find the actual streaming MRL.

In the VLC source code, the script is located here:

> vlc/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua

my question is how to extract this script to use alone without dependencies from VLC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [get the script](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=blob_plain;f=share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua), but you won't be able to make it work outside of VLC, simply because it's using VLC API calls (like `vlc.stream`) that are only available when you run it in VLC.

Comment: so is there any way to pick the least corresponding VLC codes together to use?

Comment: The easiest way is probably try to run it outside of VLC and see where it fails; then try to see if it's a critical part or if you can stub the call on which it fails with your own function that does something similar without using VLC API. Not saying it's easy or possible, but this is what I'd try.